# .Net C# Connector/NET Query with parameters not working

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm making a login in asp.net. The query to fetch a user from the database always returns an empty set even when there should be a row back.

I'm using Connector/NET with c#

I have the query to get the user by email declared like this:
    `select * from users where email = '@email';`

In the database I have two rows: test1@example.com and test2@example.com

My code looks like this: 
UserByEmail is a string with the query as seen above.

```
    MySqlCommand query = new MySqlCommand(UserByEmail, db);
    db.Open();
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
    MySqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();
    if(reader.Read()){
       /* Do stuff */
    }
    db.Close();
```

When I run it like this with any of the test cases, the property `reader.HasRows` always returns false. I've changed the query directly to:

```
- select * from users;
- select * from users where email = 'test1@example.com';
```

And for both of them, there are rows back. So the problem is when I use the parameter *@email* and the `query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);`.

Any idea what's happening here? I've looked for this problem and have find nothing. The code is almost the same as in the doc's example ( [Connector/NET Tutorials: Parameters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `'` from sides of `'@email'` as addwith value adds it where necessary:

```
string query = "select * from users where email = @email"
```

By the way, its better to use `Parameters.Add()`, instead of `Parameters.AddWithValue()`:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've lost hours to this and it was the quotes. I'll use the way you recommend to add the parameters.